# Replace [social-networking] tag with two separate and specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There are two broad groups of questions using the [social-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-networking) tag, with also substantial confusion between how the tag is being used and the official description of the tag.

The first group could be tagged [social-network-analysis]. This is a data structure, set of methods, and a scientific field as defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network_analysis) with questions such as how to implement search algorithms. See typical question [Specify LinkDistance and LinkStrength for Curved Links in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034720/specify-linkdistance-and-linkstrength-for-curved-links-in-d3) or [NetLogo Efficient way to create fixed number of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967388/netlogo-efficient-way-to-create-fixed-number-of-links).

The existing tag description is *"A social network is a social structure made up of individuals (or organizations) called "nodes", which are tied (connected) by one or more specific types of interdependency, such as ..."* and should be retained for this tag.

The second group could be tagged [social-networking-sites] and includes questions such as how to program links to Facebook. See typical question [Securing user profile retrieve from Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131153/securing-user-profile-retrieve-from-facebook-login) or [Android sharing google play install referrer url in social networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935116/android-sharing-google-play-install-referrer-url-in-social-networks). Wikipedia calls this [Social networking service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_networking_service)

The new tag description would be something like "Social networking or social media sites are web based services for friends or people with similar interests or activities to interact. Popular platforms include Facebook, Google+ and Twitter."

The two proposed tags start with the same letters so both would be visible from a search, which may help to limit mis-tagging.

**UPDATE** Now seeking votes and/or comments to decide whether to undertake this

So the suggestion is:

1. burninate [social-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-networking)
2. retag questions with either [social-network-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-network-analysis) or [social-networking-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-networking-sites) depending on content

When I created this request, there were 1,741 questions that would potentially need retagging, though many have 0 votes so the required workload would be lower.

Comment: I don't think we want a tag for this kind of task*s* (yes, that's an s). If that was the case, website and program would be the most popular tags on SO, because most are either trying to build a website or a program.

Comment: So @Braiam, are you suggesting that the [social-networking] tag simply be removed from the questions in the second category, and left with their language tags and the type of problem left to the title and description?

Comment: Yes, most information can be conveyed more effectively that way. What can be objectively categorized, on tags; everything else body and title.