# How should tags get disambiguated?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was recently awarded the tumbleweed badge for [Replace [social-networking] tag with two separate and specific tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308087/suggest-split-social-networking-tag) (yay me). Looking at the list of questions tagged with [tag-disambiguation] it is clear that my proposal was unusual in attracting no response, but there's quite a lot with very few votes. Nevertheless, cleaning up tags makes SO a more useful site.

I can not find any documentation about how these suggestions for disambiguation eventually get actioned. There are two obvious options:

(1) Vote based system - automatically approved if upvotes exceeds downvotes by some amount. This would appear sensible, but requires people to actually vote.

(2) Review queue - this is a fairly standard way for SO to handle such issues. It obviously adds some reviewing tasks, but the number of disambiguation proposals is very small. The more serious problem is that the decision might require specialist knowledge.

Another option (if the StackExchange platform supports it) might be (2) but declining requires a reason and that can be challenged. This alleviates some of the specialist knowledge problem.

Is there already a process (and please let me know where I can find it)? If not, I will set up a feature request based on any discussion this question generates.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the guidance for disambiguation is the same as for burnination. Provided, of course that the consensus isn't something that requires moderator/developer intervention like automated merging or blacklisting.

The guidance for when to call Trogdor the mighty is:

> This should be decided on a case-to-case basis. You should take into account the popularity of the tag, how long ago the Meta discussion was posted, the post score (preferably break this down into the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes, not just the resulting score) and comments or answers giving convincing reasons one way or the other, especially those by high-reputation users and moderators.
>
> Popular tags should be given more time and/or a higher score before deciding to proceed with burnination.
>
> Comments by high-reputation users and moderators saying that they don't agree with the burnination (presumably with good reason) should increase the threshold on the score or time a bit. Comments in themselves shouldn't decide requests if the score isn't in line with them.
>
> Very controversial requests (ones with many upvotes and downvotes) should preferably be given some time to settle down to a convincingly either high or low score.

*(So I don't incur the wrath of [Bob](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5337149/bob) :), the quote comes from the Meta FAQ [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work))*

---

Tangental issue: No pun in the tag split request's title.  Off the top of my head here's the first title I could come up with:

> The [social-networking] tag's relationship status is complicated