# Tag only edits should not bump

Tags: feature-request, tags

We all want tags to be useful. The tag clean up (synonym or burninate) processes fix those tags silently, no bumping of the affected questions. In the same vein, I think it would be useful if edits that were only tag changes did not bump the question.

There's been several meta questions suggesting that minor edits don't bump, such as ["'Bumping' question after editing" feature should be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262813/bumping-question-after-editing-feature-should-be-removed/288379#288379) and [Should VERY MINOR edits, NOT be bumped to the top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267623/should-very-minor-edits-not-be-bumped-to-the-top). As far as I can tell, these have all been opposed, at least partially to limit the potential for vandalism. However, I think the potential for retagging as vandalism is much lower.

There are two tags that I use that really need some cleaning. Both have fairly small numbers. Questions that should be [agent-based-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agent-based-modeling) sometimes get tagged as [agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agent), such as [python multi agent simulation packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423372/python-multi-agent-simulation-packages). The other is [social-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-networking) which keeps on being added to posts that are about Facebook or other social media sites. I have tried to get this dealt with using ambiguity processes (see [Replace [social-networking] tag with two separate and specific tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308087/replace-social-networking-tag-with-two-separate-and-specific-tags)) but the proposal was essentially ignored. However, there are proper Facebook tags, so I would be happy to go through the questions manually, removing the inappropriate tag and adding an appropriate one.

I did do a few tag edits manually (making other edits as appropriate) and then realised this was bumping the question so stopped.

Comment: Dunno, I say bump away and especially if mistagged. To me, updating the tag is a pretty good reason to bump a thread and potentially make it catch attention from the right people. I actually think bumping is a desirable behavior here -- the addition or removal of tags is a pretty substantial change, perhaps even more than a title change. Bumps are annoying with trivial edits, but I think retagging is far, far from trivial.

Comment: Like why do we retag? I think there's the posterity reason -- add this question to the right place so that it can be found later. But probably a more immediate concern (except for the most epic up-voted questions) is to make the question get the attention from the right people. Without the bump, it kind of loses that effect -- a question mistagged originally could otherwise forever be doomed to be overlooked. A retag should kind of make the question "fresh" again IMO.

Comment: Related, but a more-specific case: [Tag-removal-only edits shouldn't add closed questions to the Reopen Review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307042/tag-removal-only-edits-shouldnt-add-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue)